# What's an elegant way to create a list of objects a list of other objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine I have two dataclasses:

```
class A:
   x: int
   y: int

class B:
   x:int
   y:int
```

And I have a list of class a:

`a_list = [A(x=1, y=2), A(x=3,y=4), ...]`

What would be an elegant way of creating a list of class B from this list (copying the properties over in each case)?

Comment: Is this a style question (like "Should I implement an `A.to_b()` method or a `B.from_a()` method or a `a_to_b()` function or something else?") or an implementation question (like "How do I write a list comprehension?")?

Answer (score 2):

Give `B` a class method that produces an instance of `B` given an instance of `A`:

```
class B
    x: int
    y: int

    @classmethod
    def from_A(cls, a):
        return cls(a.x, a.y)
```

Then you can write

```
bs = [B.from_A(a) for a in a_list]
```

---

There's a bit of an asymmetry here: `B` knows details about `A`, but `A` knows nothing about `B`. You could reverse this and let instances of `A` produce instances of `B`:

```
class A:
   x: int
   y: int

   def to_B(self):
       return B(self.x, self.y)

bs = [a.to_B() for a in a_list]
```

Or, you could decide that neither `A` nor `B` should be "privileged" to know details about the other, instead having a third "omniscient" entity that knows how to go in one direction or the other.  (This is at least symmetrical.)

```
def b_from_a(a):
    return B(a.x, a.y)

bs = [b_from_a(a) for a in a_list]
```

How you decide to encapsulate the creation of a `B` from an `A` is up to you; other factors in your code may help you decide which of the three options is most reasonable.

Comment: Whichever of my or C.Nivs' approaches you choose to go with, I encourage you to *also* follow this answer's advice. Either approach will look much better wrapped in a `classmethod` with a good docstring.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both are dataclasses and all of the names match up, you can pass `A` as keyword arguments to `B`'s constructor using [`asdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict).

```
my_b_object = B(**asdict(my_a_object))
```

and, of course, to apply it over a list, use a list comprehension.

```
b_list = [B(**asdict(a)) for a in a_list]
```

Comment: Using `vars` instead of `asdict` would make this work with non-dataclasses as well.

Comment: `vars` is far more general than `asdict`, though.

Comment: Actually, `asdict` won't work correctly if `A` has another dataclass as an attribute, since it recursively converts *all* dataclass instances to dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Access the attributes directly and feed them into `B`:

```py
b_list = [B(a.x, a.y) for a in a_list]
```